# Name of decision method in which probability of taking an action is exactly past successes / past attempts, while alternative actions normalize

Tags: probability, terminology, machine-learning, decision-theory

The probability of choosing among options $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $...X_n$ is initially uniform, *i.e.* $P(X_j)=1/n$. On choosing $X_j$, either success or failure will occur (with unknown probabilities, but irrelevant to this question), and $P(X_j)$ immediately becomes $$\frac{\text{Past Successes of }X_j}{\text{Past Successes of }X_j + \text{Past Failures of }X_j}$$

while the probability of the rest of the options diminish proportionally, to normalize the space.

I know in general this is known as "reinforcement learning," but I'm wondering if there's a specific name for this exact, naive algorithm (or the class of such in which this is an instance).

Allow me to walk through a quick example:

1. We have options A, B, and C, the probability of each being, initially, $\frac{1}{3}$.
2. We choose option B, and it succeeds. Therefore, the probability of B is now $\frac{1}{1+0}$, and the probabilities of A and C adjust to $0$ in order to normalize the probability space to 1.
3. We then choose, helplessly, option B again, since its probability is 1. This time, it fails. Therefore, the probability of B is now $\frac{1}{1+1}$, and the probabilities of A and C adjust to $\frac{1}{4}$.
4. We then choose, by chance, option C, and it fails, too. Therefore, the probability of C is now $\frac{0}{0+1}$, and the probabilities of A and B, formerly $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$, adjust to $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$.

And so on and so forth.

**Is there a specific name by which this algorithm is known?**

(And in case I'm curious later, as I wouldn't like to ask a separate question for this, is there a name for this algorithm but with decaying "memory" of past successes and failures? I imagine it'd simply be descriptive, *e.g.* "**__** with a decaying function." But, it'd be great if there was a name by which an audience would know exactly the system I'm talking about.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is basically just a discrete Bayesian decision model. I'm not sure I've seen exactly your update rule, but the general process can be made with any probability distributions.

Comment: Hm, is there an even simpler update rule (that still takes into account the entire history)? To me the above seemed as naive as one could get, so I thought there must be a canonical name... Thanks though, "Bayesian decision model" led me to [a stats.SE page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20235/are-there-any-tutorials-on-bayesian-probability-theory-or-graphical-models-by-ex) that seems useful.

Comment: Actually, I'm being dumb. This is exactly what is called the Naive Bayes Classifier, but usually you would read off the probabilities from a training set all at once. This is just a conversion of that algorithm to fit into a decision theory framework. Often times your rule is exactly what pops out of a more complicated form of analysis where you estimate discrete values with a continuous distribution (like the beta for determining the bias of a coin).

Comment: For example, I blogged about this recently where I used the beta distribution to update my beliefs about the bias of a coin after each flip and make guesses about whether or not it would come up heads or tails, but that analysis led to the exact update rule you propose: http://hilbertthm90.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/decision-theory-2/

Comment: It's reinforcement learning with a specific (i.e., linear) functional form. You are right reinforcement learning is more general, since you might also use, say, a logit specification for $P(X_j)$.

Comment: @Matt or \@Nameless, if either of you wanted to add an answer, I'll accept.